# PyQt string split returning an memory address rather than the string split

Tags: python, string, pyqt, qstring

Hello I am having an issue with PyQt when it comes to splitting an string.

I am currently grabbing the input text from a TextEdit field and splitting the string inputted into a list.

```
    start_token = self.serialInputText.toPlainText()
    split_start = start_token.split(' ')
    print start_token + '\r\n'
    print split_start
```

However whenever I print this to see what my new string list is I get the following:

`<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0x10b18a488>`

Which i believe is the memory address of the StringList. Instead I would like to print the StringList out and view it to make sure it is functioning correctly.

I have tried a different approach and imported `import sip` and used `sip.setapi("QString", 2)` and then when i print my StringList it will appear as the following:

`[u'Dog', u'Cat', u'Bird', u'Animals', u'Tigers', u'Etc']`

which is fine however it's adding a `u` to every entry in the list.

Simply put, I want to have a TextEdit field and text will be inputted into that field. Then that text needs to be separated via a space delimiter to be used for another function later on in the program.

Comment: the `u'string'` just means it's unicode - normal for gui toolkits, and works just like a regular string. as far as the address - unlike many other languages, objects in python tend to have built-in visualizers via `repr` or `str` (or sometimes it's in the console). for 'foreign' objects, that's usually the default representation. in short, everything is probably right, and you're just getting thrown off by visualization artifacts.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm new to python and PyQt I had was confused by the visualization. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanP. That was a very good idea to use `sip.setapi`, as it will save you at lot of hassle in the long run (you should also consider doing the same thing for `QVariant`). However, it would be even better if you used python3, as you will get the same behaviour by default (i.e. no need to use sip). And as an extra bonus, there's no `u` prefixes in python3.

Comment: @ekhumoro I was thinking of using Python 3 however all of my program's core was made on python 2.7 and the Im still fairly new so i didnt wanna go back and forth between these two versions. I will start using Python3 in my future projects though. Thank you for the tip for `QVariant`